# Code in a lambda function not called at all

Tags: lambda

I am neither a Node.js nor a AWS Lambda expert, so I might do something wrong.
I wrote the code below, which works fine when executed from the command line using AWS CLI but simply does not get called in a lambda function.

Can you tell me what to look for or out to debug this to understand the reason?
Thanks.

---

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
var params = {
Bucket: 'nicobucket1',
Body: 'hellolll',
Key: 'mykey',
};
var s3 = new aws.S3();
console.log('Created S3 object, invoking upload...' + JSON.stringify(s3));
s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
console.log('...in function upload...');
if(err){ 
console.log(err);
context.fail('Could not create object in bucket...');
}
else console.log ('Uploaded data, check the console...');
});

context.succeed('Created object in S3 bucket!'); 
};
```

I see all console.log messages in the logs except the ones in the s3.upload function. Of course the objects are not created.
From the command line everything is fine.

---

Answer (score 0):

Your `context.succeed();` is most likely executing before `s3.upload()` has had a chance to complete.  Try moving your `context.succeed()'` line into the s3.upload function.  I also noticed that there is an extra comma in your params after 'mykey'.  I've tried the following modified version of your code and it was successful.

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'nicobucket1-unique',
        Body: 'hellolll',
        Key: 'mykey'
        };
    
    var s3 = new aws.S3();
    
    console.log('Created S3 object, invoking upload...' + JSON.stringify(s3));
    
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
        console.log('...in function upload...');
        
        if(err){ 
            console.log(err);
            context.fail('Could not create object in bucket...');
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log ('Uploaded data, check the console...');
            context.succeed('Created object in S3 bucket!');
        }
         
    });
    
};
```

Hope this helps someone.